# How to fix "Cannot find name 'hbspt'" while embeding Hubspot form to React app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, hubspot, hubspot-crm

```
 useEffect(() => {
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "//js-eu1.hsforms.net/forms/embed/v2.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);

script.addEventListener("load", () => {
  // @TS-ignore
  if (hbspt) {
    // @TS-ignore
    window.hbspt.forms.create({
      portalId: "YOUR_PORTAL_ID_HERE",
      formId: "YOUR_FORM_ID_HERE",
      target: "#hubspotForm",
    });
  }
});
  }, []);
```

I found this code for embeding my form to my react component, but I keep getting error
`Cannot find name 'hbspt'.` (I am using typescript btw)

Comment: The problem is that to disable typescript for a line the comment is lower-case `TS`, so the comments should be `// @ts-ignore`

Answer (score 0):

be careful that your code will import the hubspot horrible javascript inside your page multiple times.

consider doing this: 
inside the index.html meta parts add the javascript import

```
<script
      charset="utf-8"
      type="text/javascript"
      src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/embed/v2.js"
></script>
```

makes the useEffect doing only the placement in the page

```
  useEffect(() => {
    /* eslint-disable */
    if (hbspt) {
      /* eslint-disable */
      window.hbspt.forms.create({
        region: "[...]",
        portalId: "[...]",
        formId: "[...]",
        target: "#hubspotForm",
      });
    }
  }, []);
```